# Open specific Folder in excel using vb.net in VisualStudio

Tags: excel, vb.net, add-in

I have to update an add-in that not written by me and i have to add a button that opens the specific path. I have no idea about this add-in. I could just add the button...

```
    Private Sub RBOpenFolder_OnClick(sender As Object, control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean) Handles RBOpenFolder.OnClick

    End Sub
```

....\AppData\Local\AppName I have to access this address but the path changes on each pc has this add-in.

So in my computer C:\Users\Taylan\AppData\Local\AppName

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly, you are trying to access the user's local AppData folder via your application.

To achieve this, simply use the `Environment.GetFolderPath` and specify the local application data folder:

```
Dim FolderNameAs String

FolderName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

In your case, this would return:

```
C:\Users\Taylan\AppData\Local\
```

You will then need to append the remainder of your path to this, so add `AppName`:

```
FolderName = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderName, "AppName")
```

The `FolderName` variable will then contain:

```
C:\Users\Taylan\AppData\Local\AppName
```

Comment: That's really fast Martin Thank you so much. I clearly understand how to get the path. Now im curious about when the button clicked how can i see the folder inside?

Comment: @Maestro00 You want to get a list of the contents of the folder in VB.Net?

Comment: In the add-in. When the user click this button in excel add-in they will see the folder inside and maybe delete something in it.

Comment: @Maestro00 Check Directory.GetFiles https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8